# Why won't iPhone mail connected to an Exchange account download email bodies?

Tags: iphone, email, exchange-activesync

I bought an iPhone 4 today and after alot of fiddling around I got it connected to Microsoft Exchange Activesync. Mail shows the message headers correctly and a preview of the first line from the body. When I click on any of the message headers, it displays the header information but then it just sits their loading the message body.

Eventually it times out and says: `The message has not been downloaded from the server`

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Strangely, after a day or two it has now started working. It has happened once or twice intermittently, but the problem seems to be largely resolved.

There wasn't anything in particular that I did to fix it.

Comment: I started getting a similar problem to this again. I wasn't getting the error, but email bodies were not rendering. The email would show and the message body would be empty. Also, I couldn't click in the body of a new message I was writing to add text. 
Restarting the iPhone fixed the problem.

Comment: Also applies to Exchange Email on iPad. Content missing from email body, with no error messages to indicate a problem. Only setting changed on iPad prior to this happening, was changing the time zone settings. Restarting iPad definitely worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check iphone date and time:

Settings->General->date and time.
If its point to Automatic, set Automatically OFF
Time Zone: Setup your current time zone.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue which appears to be router specific and only related to emails from an Exchange server as Gmail works fine.

I have both iphone and ipad which work seamlessly on 3G and the first time I check emails on arrival at home on the wireless network. When I check a second time, the headers appear in the phone / ipad although nothing appears in the body, no matter how long the phone is left.

If you go to airplane mode and back, the symptoms are the same as arriving at home. Works one time and then doesn't.

I have proved this to the router as I purchased a Thompson TG845 (which is awful to setup) and it works consistently. When I install my preferred Netgear routers, the above problem exists even if I set the iphone in the DMZ.

Exceedingly frustrating and it appears as if I'm not the only one to experience this.

Changing the time to manual as suggested had no effect neither did aligning it to the Exchange servers time.

Look forward to anyone with the techo answer.